# about embedded document referencing many other documents

Tags: reference, document, mongoid

I have a following association

```
Class Person 
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_many :employments
end

Class Employment
    include Mongoid::Document
    references_many :centres
end

class Centre
    include Mongoid::Document
    referenced_in :employment
end
```

Now when I tried

`Person.first.employments.first.centres.build` it gave me errors like

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `centres' for #<Employment:0x000001023f38f8>
```

Am i doing any thing wrong?

Or the embedded document cannot reference many other documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, you setup is wrong. Embedded document cannot reference other model. If you still want to reference another model with embedded document, then you will have to create custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Centre
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :employment, :inverse_of => :centres
end
```